# Are variable keys in chrome.storage.local isolated?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm creating a Chrome extension that saves data through a content-script.

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ "settings": data})
```

Now I'm using the key-name `settings`, which is a pretty common name.

Are key/values in `chrome.storage.local` scoped or isolated to the extension? Or should I prefix my keys so that my variables potentially won't get overridden by other extensions?

Comment: It might help you [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173576)

Comment: It would be a fairly serious security issue if extension/site storage were not isolated.

Comment: The storage is isolated.